# SQL SELECT WHERE IN another SELECT with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: sql, mariadb

Good Day,

I have 3 Tables - Ticket, Ticket Batch (Multiple Ticket Rows To One Batch) and Ticket Staff (Multiple Staff Rows To One Ticket) and wish to ultimately UPDATE the ticket_batch table with the COUNT of all staff working on tickets per ticket batch.

The tables with applicable columns look as follows

ticket:

```
| ticket_number | recon_number |
```

ticket_batch:

```
| recon_number |
```

ticket_staff:

```
| ticket_number |
```

So I have written the following SQL query to essentially first if I do get the COUNT:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ticket_staf
 WHERE ticket_staff.ticket_number IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ticket.ticket_number) FROM ticket WHERE ticket.recon_number = 1);
```

Which the query just keeps running, but when I execute the queries separately:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ticket.ticket_number)
 FROM ticket
 WHERE ticket.recon_number = 1;
```

I get 5 ticket numbers within split seconds and if I paste that string in the other portion of the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ticket_staff
WHERE ticket_staff.ticket_number IN (1451,1453,1968,4457,4458);
```

It returns the correct COUNT.

So ultimately I guess can I not write queries with GROUP_CONCATS into another SELECT WHERE IN? And how should I structure my query?

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` doesn't look right.  I suspect you are confusing a *list of values* for `IN` with a *string*.  They are not the same thing.

In general, I would recommend `EXISTS` over `IN` anyway:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ticket_staff ts
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ticket t
              WHERE ts.ticket_number = t.ticket_number AND 
                    t.recon_number = 1
             );
```

For this query, you want an index on `ticket(ticket_number, recon_number)`.  However, I am guessing that `ticket(ticket_number)` is the primary key, which is enough of an index by itself.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `Inner join` as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct ts.*)
  FROM ticket_staff ts
  LEFT JOIN ticket t
    ON ts.ticket_number = t.ticket_number 
 WHERE t.recon_number = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Popeye, thanks for the answer :)
I tested it, but unfortunately the query didnt execute on phpMyAdmin (think it was unhappy about the asterisk)